# New to programing. Trying to add the same text to the end of all data entries in a column using python 3

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-3.x

I am hoping to use Python 3 to write this program but I will use whatever language is best for the job. I have DB named "places" in **MySQL**. In this DB there is a column containing street names and the number of homes under the column header "locations". I want to add the text ", New York City, NY" to the end of every current record in the column. I know how to write the code for connecting the DB to the program, however, I just am unsure what commands to use to get my desired result. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [`concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to add the desired text to the column.

This should be doable in any language that has a module that allows direct SQL interaction with *MySQL*, including *Python 3*.